# CORS error in node express REST API (PATCH Request)

Tags: node.js, rest, express, cors

I'm getting cors error for patch request. I'm using cors npm package, It's working well for get and post request. for patch method throwing cors error.

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();

app.use(cors());
```

I added options app.options('*', cors()), no luck not working.

Error:
*Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://example.com/url' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: Method PATCH is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are able to pass option to cors middleware , I hope this will help

```
var options = {
  "origin": "*",
  "methods": "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
  "preflightContinue": false,
  "optionsSuccessStatus": 204
}
app.use(cors(options));
```

Comment: Thanks, Working in chrome incognito mode not working in normal chrome browser.I'm using chrome 87 version

Answer (score 0):

Nothing works for me, so all I do was change all my PATCH requests for PUT request.

This happens because the `cors()` doesn't add PATCH to the accepted methods and neither one of this options worked.